How to open the File Explorer at the push of a button in a C# Windows Forms App?
I'm making a To-Do List using Windows Forms, and currently I'm working with MS Access. And I need help on how to open and Access file in the file explorer upon the push of a button.
Here is my code:
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace todolistApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataTable todoList = new DataTable();
        bool isEditing = false;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            todoList.Columns.Add("Title");
            todoList.Columns.Add("Description");

            todolistView.DataSource = todoList;
        }

        private void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            titletextBox.Text = "";
            descriptiontextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isEditing = true;

            titletextBox.Text = todoList.Rows[todolistView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            descriptiontextBox.Text = todoList.Rows[todolistView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        }

        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                todoList.Rows[todolistView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isEditing)
            {
                todoList.Rows[todolistView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]["Title"] = titletextBox.Text;
                todoList.Rows[todolistView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]["Description"] = titletextBox.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                todoList.Rows.Add(titletextBox.Text, descriptiontextBox.Text);
            }
            titletextBox.Text = "";
            descriptiontextBox.Text = "";
            isEditing = false;

        }

        private void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in todoList.Rows)
            {
                string constring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"E:\\Downloads\\coding stuf\\todolistApp\\todolistApp\\todolistDB.accdb\"";
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 ([Title], [Description]) VALUES (@title,@description)", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", row["Title"].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", row["Description"].ToString());

                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("All rows inserted.");
        }

        private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}


Upon clicking the loadButton, it should open a file explorer window to open an Access File. But I do not know exactly how to do that.
I tried to check other stackoverflow questions, but none of them answered my query. I'm expecting a file explorer window opening so that the user can open an Access file to export all of the To-Do List rows from the DataGrid. I'm a beginner C# dev and please bare with me if the code is very messy.

You probably don’t want to open Explorer that lets users just browse files, but the Open File Dialog, which allows users to select one or more files to open. Your app gets the path(s) back.
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Access Databases (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Get the path of specified file
        var filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        // Do something with the file path.
    }
}

See https://learn.microsoft.com/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog for more information.
